# Why is my makefile not working as expected?

Tags: makefile

Here is my makefile:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-I.
DEPS = settings.h
OBJ = settings.o tomato.o
EXDIR = $(ROOT_TOMATO)/bin
OBJDIR = $(ROOT_TOMATO)/obj

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<

$(EXDIR)/tomato: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f a.out *.o

all: tomato
```

On line 9 and 10, I have attempted to get it to create object files and put them in the `OBJDIR`, but it instead places the obj files in the current directory, ROOT_TOMATO/src:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<
```

I can't figure out why it is not working. Perhaps there are better ways, but I also like to know why my code doesn't work in this particular case.

As a side note, the makefile is called by another makefile:

```
#Main makefile for project

#Get root compile directory
ROOT_TOMATO = $(shell pwd)
export ROOT_TOMATO

All:
   $(MAKE) -C src
```

Comment: If you have a problem with lines 9 and 10, you should remove anything about EXDIR from your makefile before asking the question.  Your example is not minimal.  There is also a lots of other garbage in your makefile which is not relevant to your question.  -1 for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you say

```
$(EXDIR)/tomato: $(OBJ)
```

The prerequisites for `$(EXDIR)/tomato` are not `$(OBJDIR)/settings.o` and `$(OBJDIR)/tomato.o` but just plain `settings.o` and `tomato.o`, as you defined in `OBJ`. Therefore, the pattern rule is not used to build them, and make falls back on implicit rules to build `settings.o` and `tomato.o`.

You could instead use

```
$(EXDIR)/tomato: $(OBJ:%=$(OBJDIR)/%)
```

...or set `OBJ` so that it contains these paths from the get-go.

Note that your `clean` rule has a similar problem, so having a variable that contains the actual object paths would be sensible. You could use it both in the `$(EXDIR)/tomato` prerequisites and in the `clean` recipe.

Also note that the default rule for the inner Makefile is not `all` but `$(EXDIR)/tomato`, because it is the first for a specific target. It's sort of a good thing here; the `all` rule would not work as intended because its prerequisite is `tomato`, for which there is no rule, rather than `$(EXDIR)/tomato`. I suspect you'll want to fix that and move the `all` rule to the top at some point, though.

Answer (score 0):

`Make` is a language where ‘keep it simple’ is *great* advice.  It's a language where simple things are simple; hard things look like line-noise.

Remember that Make is a sort of executable build-process documentation – readability is a Good Thing.

I'd rewrite your Makefile as something like

```
CXX=g++
OBJ=settings.o tomato.o
TARGET=tomato

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $<


# default target
$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJ) $(CFLAGS)

tomato.o: settings.h
settings.o: settings.h

clean:
    rm $(TARGET) *.o
```

That is:

1. It's conventional to use `CXX` as the macro for the C++ compiler, and leave `CC` for the C compiler – that prompts anyone reading the rules to jump to the right conclusion.
2. Keep the `%.o: %cpp` rule simple.  So, you end up with lots of `*.o` files in the current directory - big deal!  Put them in your Mercurial/Git ignore file and move on.  You *can* put them into another directory, and @Wintermute shows how to do that, but it needs more punctuation, and doesn't really gain much.
3. Notice how I haven't needed to use any `$(VAR:sub=result)` constructions.  They're useful, but if you use too many of them, the result quickly becomes unreadable.
4. Be reluctant to put dependencies in `%` rules.  Expressing those separately in action-less rules (as with the dependencies for `tomato.o` and `settings.o`) documents that ‘there's nothing fancy about these modules’ *and* keeps everything looking cleaner.

A complicated makefile which does *everything* automatically is a great way of procrastinating (take it from me, oh brother...).

Comment: This may all be good advice, but it bears no relation whatever to the question that was asked, which was how to put the object files in a separate directory.